# SQL Server: emailing the results of a dynamic SQL query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to build a loop with a cursor in order to send a list of backorders to clients having such backorders.

The `WHILE` loop with the cursor is ok, and I am fetching the current `@idClient` and `@email` correctly, but I don't know how to have the query filtered on `@idClient`.

Here is the (non working) statement I made so far:

```
exec msdb..sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='sql_mail_lu',
                    @recipients = @email,
                    @subject = 'Your backorders',
                    @body = 'Please find in attachment the list of your items in backorder.',
                    @execute_query_database = 'ERPSQL', 
                    @query = '
                              SELECT TOP 100
                              NoDoc, Refer Product, Comm Ordered, isnull(Livr, 0) Delivered, BackOrder, VRef
                              FROM erpSQL.dbo.vwBoClients
                              WHERE idclient = ' + @idClient' ,
                    @attach_query_result_as_file = 1, 
                    @query_attachment_filename ='backorders.txt'
```

My question is: how should I formulate the `@query =` part to make it work ?

Comment: and what error do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape those single quotations:

```
exec msdb..sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='sql_mail_lu',
                    @recipients=@email,
                    @subject='Your backorders',
                    @body= 'Please find in attachment the list of your items in backorder.',
                    @execute_query_database = 'ERPSQL', 
                    @query = '
                              SELECT TOP 100
                              NoDoc, Refer Product, Comm Ordered, isnull(Livr, 0) Delivered, BackOrder, VRef
                              FROM   erpSQL.dbo.vwBoClients
                              WHERE  idclient = ''' + @idClient + ''' ,
                    @attach_query_result_as_file = 1, 
                    @query_attachment_filename =''backorders.txt'''
```

Comment: If @idClient is a string then you must use [`QUOTENAME(...,''')`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx) to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: This is a procedure not a client side application.

Comment: That changes nothing. Its is an exploitable vector for SQL injection.